# Find matrix corresponding to sequence

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, diagonalization

Assuming I have the sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ defined by $a_n=a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}$, I need to find a matrix $2$x$2$ corresponding to the given sequence.

I know the answer, but I don't understand why this is it.

Will appreciate some explanation.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by a "matrix corresponding to the sequence"? What is the matrix supposed to do?

Comment: Have you seen "matrix representations" for similar sequences like the Fibonacci sequence, which also has a similar linear recurrence? Read section 3 of the document [here](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~pavel/fibonacci.pdf).

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes of course that I have seen it, but it is given with no explanation why they picked it.

Comment: @CalculusLover Let the matrix we require be called $M$. The matrix $M$ is designed so that $\begin{pmatrix} a_{n+2} \\ a_{n+1}\end{pmatrix} = M \begin{pmatrix} a_{n+2} \\ a_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}$ for all $n$. The point is simple : we convert the idea of finding $a_n$ , into the idea of matrix exponentiation (since we can repeat this to get $$\begin{pmatrix} a_{n+2} \\ a_{n+1}\end{pmatrix} = M^n \begin{pmatrix} a_{2} \\ a_{1}\end{pmatrix})$$, so we only need to know $M^n$), and matrix exponentiation is well-studied.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I understand the second part of your answer, but not the first one, can you explain why we are looking for $M$ such that $\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n+2}\\ 
a_{n+1}
\end{pmatrix} = M\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n+2}\\ 
a_{n+1}
\end{pmatrix}$, Thanks!

Comment: @CalculusLover Oh dear, that's a typo! I meant $M \begin{pmatrix} a_{n+1} \\ a_n\end{pmatrix}$ in the RHS of that expression. There's an answer below that mentions what $M$ is : but the point is, I want to be able to talk about going from $a_{1}$ to $a_m$ by doing the same thing again and again : that's what recursion is about. Since we don't know how to understand repeated recursion, the idea of finding $M$, *transforms* the idea of repeated recursion to repeated *multiplication* of a matrix (or *exponentiation*), which we understand much more clearly.

Comment: This is basically the mathematical principle of reducing your problem to a problem whose answer you know or has been well-studied, using good equivalences. Now, I can discard the recursion and think about how to exponentiate $M$, which , as it turns out, is not too difficult!

Comment: Great @TeresaLisbon - thank you so much! You really helped me here!

Comment: @CalculusLover Always good to be helping people : from a site point of view, when you ask questions in the future, you will do well to read [How to ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and you can use it to format your future questions so that they don't get any downvotes and/or close votes. This question did not match some standards, so I wanted to answer using comments . If you can edit the question now to adjust to the "good question" norms, I'll be happy to up vote and your question will have some attention as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the document shared by @TeresaLisbon, you want to find a matrix $M$ such that$$\begin{bmatrix}a_n\\a_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}=M\begin{bmatrix}a_{n-1}\\a_{n-2}\end{bmatrix}$$We know that $a_n=a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}$, so the first row of $M$ is $[1,6]$. And $a_{n-1}=1a_{n-1}+0a_{n-2}$, so the second row is $[1,0]$, giving:$$M=\begin{bmatrix}1&6\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! The answer says $\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 
 6& 1
\end{bmatrix}$ but I think it works the same.

Comment: @CalculusLover In that case you must be looking for a matrix that performs the following:$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{n-1}\\a_n\end{bmatrix}=M\begin{bmatrix}a_{n-2}\\a_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$$That's why I asked in the beginning what is the matrix supposed to do. Not a huge difference though.